# In Git, after releasing a version, do I fork or branch the next version?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm a git noob, and after some tutorials and messing around I got some code posted on bitbucket.  Now that I have a 1.0, do I *fork* or *branch* the code to continue working?  I want to be able to go back and pick out individual versions.  Maybe I have to do neither, that this is just an inherent ability of git?

Comment: I've seen *tags* being used to mark specific versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to fork. Forking means taking a copy of the project and developing it in a different direction, usually by different developers

Have a look at this article on git workflow http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

The model can then be enforced by extending git with gitflow https://github.com/nvie/gitflow

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm too much of a noob to extend git any further =).  Btw you posted a duplicate link from another answer

Comment: @JustinXXVII - he posted a duplicate :-) my answer was first :-)

Comment: You only need to extend if you want software to enforce the method - no need to if its just a few developers who understand it

Answer (score 2):

I personally use tags to mark interesting commits (e.g. `ver1.0`) and branches to manage multiple lines of development but at the end of the day, it's just what you prefer and what works for you.

A "fork" (in the git*hub* sense) is something that's conceptually different. It's a "copy" of your repository owned by someone else so I don't think it's a right way to do release management.

Comment: thanks, I'm aware that forking makes a copy but I was not clear on how that differed from branching until these answers started popping up.

Answer (score 1):

You can do pretty much whatever works best for you regarding branching and tagging, but I recommend you have a good look at [A Successful Git Branching Model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: Great article, now to absorb all the lingo from the timeline chart =)

Answer (score 1):

You can continue working in the same branch. To easily go back to the commit that marked release of version 1.0 you can use [tag](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-tag.html). See [Creating Tags](http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#creating-tags).

Answer (score 1):

I use tags for this. For example, to simply mark the last commit as a version you could do

```
git tag versionX.X.X
```

or whatever you want to call it. This just stores a pointer to that commit. If you are using Github, it makes zip downloads available of all tags also. To push these tags to a remote repository you must do

```
git push --tags
```

[More information on Github](http://learn.github.com/p/tagging.html)